# Kivy Dynamic Classes - multiple objects

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I am trying to simplify the code that generates rows with the same content multiple times by using dynamic classes as shown in the simplified example below.
So far so good, code is simpler but I'm trying to find solutions to access from python for example Label in the second row. In my old solution, I have a unique ID for each widget but now buttons and labels are defined as only ones for all rows, and they have the same ID.
Is there any possibility to access them individually?

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

Builder.load_file("test.kv")


class MyLayout(Widget):
    pass


class MyNewApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyLayout()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyNewApp().run()
```

### test.kv

```
<RowTemplate@GridLayout>:
    cols: 2
    Label:
        id: row_label
        text: 'test'
    Button:
        id: row_button
        text: 'button'

<MyLayout>
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

    GridLayout:
        size: root.width, root.height
        cols: 1
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 0, 0, 0, 1
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
        RowTemplate: #fist row
        RowTemplate: #second row
        RowTemplate: #third row
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

class RowTemplate(GridLayout):
    button_text = StringProperty('')
    label_text = StringProperty('')
```

test.kv

```
<RowTemplate>:
    cols: 2
    Label:
        id: row_label
        text: root.label_text
    Button:
        id: row_button
        text: root.button_text
```

Now you can change text dynaminally as bellow.

```
<MyLayout>:
    RowTemplate:
        label_text: 'label one'
        button_text: 'button one'
    
    RowTemplate:
        label_text: 'label two'
        button_text: 'button two'
```

Comment: Ok, but how then can  I access properties of second label ?